# ios how can i take a IMP to SEL

Tags: objective-c, ios, pointers, selector, imp

I define a function of point

```
typedef void (^ButtonClick)(id sender);
```

and i want to call it when Button click(UIButton addTarget to call ^ButtonClick function)
but it is could find the pointer.

```
-(void)addRightButton:(UIImage*)btnImage click:(ButtonClick)click{
    UIButton *modalViewButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [modalViewButton addTarget:self
      action:@selector(click) // <==== could not find pointer.Pointer errors
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // other code to add modelViewButton on View.....
}

-(void)test
{ 
    [self addRightButton:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_shuaxin_1.png"] click:^(id sender) {
         NSLog(@"it is test code");//<===never called
    }];
}
```

how to make it to SEL?

Comment: Now function, method, selector or block?

Comment: i do not understand what is your mean.

Comment: The problem is that neither do I understand what you asked. The question is incomprehensible and does not quite make sense inits current form, please consider rephrasing it.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good,and i fixed my question.

Comment: Oh, I see now. `@selector()` is not good for this, it's only good for obtaining constant selectors. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get selectors like this. (For getting selectors at runtime, use the `sel_getUid()` function). Also, you're confusing selectors and blocks. What you want is possible, but using a different approach:

```
- (void)addRightButton:(UIImage *)btnImage click:(ButtonClick)click{
    UIButton *modalViewButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [modalViewButton addTarget:click
        action:@selector(invoke)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)test
{ 
    [self addRightButton:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_shuaxin_1.png"] click:^{
        NSLog(@"it is test code");
    }];
}
```

Comment: thanks very much ,it is work.but I need to change "typedef void (^ButtonClick)(id sender)" to "typedef void (^ButtonClick)()" I do not modify the pointer function can?

Comment: @zt9788 yes you do, you can't get the sender using this approach. But please do one favor for me: learn C and Objective-C. Basically you don't know what the difference is between a selector, a function and a block... This is not good!

Comment: thanks you very much.i will learn it.